the symbol defining a cocycle ? Or rather its square?
Let S be a Riemann surface. A quasi-meromorphic function on S is a function
holomorphic everywhere except finitely many points and such that locally it can be written as $re^{\phi}$ where both r and φ meropmorphic and r
is not identically zero. Equivalently, f is quasi-meromorphic if its logarithmic derivative $\frac{df}{f}$ is a meroporphic 1-form. Observe that quasi-meromorphic functions are
not closed with respect to addition, but they form an Abelian group
with respect to multiplication. This group is denoted by H(S)
We define the symbole $\{f,g\}_{\gamma}:=exp(\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}ln(f)dln(g))g(\gamma(0))^{-deg(f)}$
where $\gamma$ is small cercle a rond $p$ psitive orienated, and $deg(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}dln(f)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{df}{f}$
The multiplicative group of the germes of quasi-meromorphic functions in the vicinity of a point $p$ and denoted $H_p$.
Given a local coordinate $z_p$ vanishes at $p$, any element $f\in H_p$ can be written in the form $f(z_p)=az_p^nexp(\sum_{i \neq 0}t_ {-i}z_p^i)$
Verifies theses properties :
$\{f,g\}_p$ does not depend on the choice of branches of the logarithm and the initial point $x=\gamma(0)$
$\{f,gh\}_p=\{f,g\}_p\{f,h\}_p$
$\{f,g\}_p\{g,f\}_p=1$
$\prod_{p\in S}\{f,g\}_p=1$
My questions are :

the symbol defining a cocycle on the group $H_p$? Or rather its square ?

To define the co cycle is it necessary to have $\{f,f\}_p=1$ ?

Is this cocycle defines a central extension $\hat{H}_p$ of the groupe $H_p$ ?



could someone help me ???

Is it that the definition of a cocycle is c(f,gh)c(g,h)=c(f,g)c(fg,h). if I understand correctly then my symbol is a cocycle ?????
